# .HTAccess redirecting rewriting pages based on partial URL pattern?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have decided to geo-tag our e-commerce website and create sub-folders for the separate countries, i.e. UK, EU, US and CA.
Currently all pages reside in:

```
http://www.example.com/buy/
```

Every product has a single page for each country. All in the buy/ sub-folder have the format of:

```
individual-product-name-gbp.html
individual-product-name-eur.html
individual-product-name-usd.html
individual-product-name-cad.html

http://www.example.com/buy/individual-product-name-gbp.html
http://www.example.com/buy/individual-product-name-eur.html
http://www.example.com/buy/individual-product-name-usd.html
http://www.example.com/buy/individual-product-name-cad.html
```

What I would like to do is 301 redirect rewrite the GBP, EUR, USD and CAD pages to the following sub-folders and format:

```
http://www.example.com/uk/individual-product-name.html
http://www.example.com/eu/individual-product-name.html
http://www.example.com/us/individual-product-name.html
http://www.example.com/ca/individual-product-name.html
```

Thank you for any help or advice.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have several such products and pages, use this

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)-gbp\.html$ /uk/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)-eur\.html$ /eu/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)-usd\.html$ /us/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^buy/(.*)-cad\.html$ /ca/$1.html [R=301,NC,L]
```